# How to restore specific project with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

As I know in `msbuild 16.5+` we can restore all missing packages (packages.config and reference) with `msbuild -t:restore -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true`

my question is how to restore missing packages for specific project or solution folder with `msbuild` command like in Visual Studio with right click on project and click Nuget package manager and click restore button?

I use visual studio 2019 16.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the project on the command line like this:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:restore,build -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how to doing that for solution folder?